# Unable to create instance of server in sts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, spring-tool-suite

```
    java.lang.Error: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:630)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 10 more
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

I am getting this error on creating new instance of pivotal server in spring tool suite.I was creating Spring boot application and i have selected pivotal server developer edition and i have selected all templates and clicked finish and then i got this above error

Comment: Any data to reproduce the issue are missing.

Comment: i have given details you can check now

Comment: ok, I can't help with java but assume you get some help then ;-)

Comment: what happens if you try to create a new instance from the command line?